# Destruction of irrelevant / typo tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, burninate-request

I can't find an answer to this after searching meta and [the help files](https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=tags): how do "typo" tags get killed off? For example, currently there are tags for [i0s7](/questions/tagged/i0s7) and [javascipt](/questions/tagged/javascipt), which are both obviously typos. [They may even be badge-hunting by people hoping to get a lot of questions tagged incorrectly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207992/how-can-we-stop-users-adding-irrelevant-tags-obviously-just-for-farming-reputat).

So, how do we get rid of these? My take so far is that it is partly automatic, like "tags that are x days old with no posts are closed automatically," and partly a moderator activity. Is this correct?

Closely related: is there any way for users to suggest destruction of a tag that is obviously irrelevant or a typo other than (1) a meta "burninate" post or (2) marking it as a synonym of a legit tag, which just perpetuates the typo's existence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tags without questions are automatically cleared once per day.

Both examples have no questions associated with them and will be gone tomorrow.

Comment: So, I guess the answer is: obvious typos get fixed in the editing process, so then the tag has no posts and gets nuked automatically. Is that correct?

Comment: You got it in one. :-)

Comment: Thanks. Will accept the answer momentarily.

Comment: @EdCottrell: please do accept the answer *permanently*, in a moment. :-P (*momentarily* means: **for** a moment, so briefly).

Comment: Ha, okay. Since we're being grammar nerds, though, [there's another definition: "at any moment :  in a moment"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/momentarily). :)

Comment: @EdCottrell: Hrmz, popular use forcing the meaning to change. Just like [*literally*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/literally) literally changing meaning as we speak.

Comment: This is literally true. :)

Comment: @EdCottrell: ha, the [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/momentarily) confirms that your use of *momentarily* is entirely North American. I can feel superiour again now. Momentarily. :-P